# Search for nested Ruby object

Tags: ruby

So I have a question I want to ask my Ruby object:

> Are there any failed scenarios in my testing results?

The object that I am inquiring looks like this:

```
=> #<Newman::Results:0x007fdcc2b48b28 @environment="dev", @build_name="customers", @build_id="119f3875-3793-4ae7-9155-78f0ce8c7047", @scenarios=[#<Newman::Scenario:0x007fdcc2b489c0 @name="POST /customers/zuora/create", @assertions=[#<Newman::Assertion:0x007fdcc2b48970 @test="Status code is 200">]>, #<Newman::Scenario:0x007fdcc2b48948 @name="GET ssoauthentication/../Authentication/token", @assertions=[#<Newman::Assertion:0x007fdcc2b488f8 @test="Status code is 200">]>, #<Newman::Scenario:0x007fdcc2b488d0 @name="GET /users?CustomerId={customerId}", @assertions=[#<Newman::Assertion:0x007fdcc2b48880 @test="Status code is 200">]>, #<Newman::Scenario:0x007fdcc2b48858 @name="GET /locations?CustomerId={customerId}", @assertions=[#<Newman::Assertion:0x007fdcc2b48808 @test="Status code is 200">]>, #<Newman::Scenario:0x007fdcc2b487e0 @name="PUT/users/{userId}/avatar", @assertions=[#<Newman::Assertion:0x007fdcc2b48790 @test="Status code is 200">]>, #<Newman::Scenario:0x007fdcc2b48768 @name="PUT /customers/{customerId}/logo", @assertions=[#<Newman::Assertion:0x007fdcc2b48718 @test="Status code is 200">]>, #<Newman::Scenario:0x007fdcc2b486f0 @name="POST /customers/{customerId}/positions", @assertions=[#<Newman::Assertion:0x007fdcc2b486a0 @test="Successful POST request", @exception_message="expected 200 to be one of [ 201, 202 ]", @exception_source="AssertionError: expected 200 to be one of [ 201, 202 ]\n   at Object.eval sandbox-script.js:1:7)">]>, #<Newman::Scenario:0x007fdcc2b48678 @name="POST /users", @assertions=[#<Newman::Assertion:0x007fdcc2b48628 @test="Status code is 200">]>, #<Newman::Scenario:0x007fdcc2b48600 @name="POST /users/{userId}/invitation", @assertions=[#<Newman::Assertion:0x007fdcc2b485b0 @test="Status code is 200">]>, #<Newman::Scenario:0x007fdcc2b48588 @name="POST /registration", @assertions=[#<Newman::Assertion:0x007fdcc2b48538 @test="Status code is 200">]>, #<Newman::Scenario:0x007fdcc2b48510 @name="PUT /users/{userId}/avatar", @assertions=[#<Newman::Assertion:0x007fdcc2b484c0 @test="Status code is 200">]>, #<Newman::Scenario:0x007fdcc2b48498 @name="post to slack", @assertions=[#<Newman::Assertion:0x007fdcc2b48448 @test="Status Code is correct">]>]>
```

...but the gist is that there's a Results object, which has a `Scenarios` array filled with 1 or more `Scenario` objects. Each `Scenario` object has an `Assertions` array filled with 1 or more `Assertion` objects, and each `Assertion` object contains an `@exception_message` attribute. This `@exception_message` attribute will be `nil` unless the assertion fails, in which case it will be `true`.

So, going back to the question ("Are there any failed scenarios in my testing results?"): what is the best way to ask this in Ruby (not Rails)?

My best attempt, where `results` is my parsed results file and true or false is my desired answer:

```
results.scenarios.to_a.find { |scenario| scenario.assertions.to_a.find { |assertion| assertion.exception_message != nil }}
```

This seems to work but there *must* be a more efficient way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a more concise way of writing your above logic:

```
results.scenarios.any? do |scenario|
  scenario.assertions.any?(&:exception_message)
end
```

However, that's still quite a complex block of logic to put in one place. You could break this down further by doing something like:

```
results.scenarios.any?(&:failed?)

class Newman::Scenario
  def failed?
    assertions.any?(&:exception_message)
  end
end
```

Or even, to take it a step further:

```
results.scenario_failed?

class Newman::Results
  def scenario_failed?
    scenarios.any?(&:failed?)
  end
end

class Newman::Scenario
  def failed?
    assertions.any?(&:exception_message)
  end
end
```

Comment: The general principle applied here, if you're interested, is called the "Law of Demeter" - aka "only talk to your neighbours". The reason your original code felt so complicated was because of the long method chains; reaching deep into a nested object model. By contrast, my refactored code is only going "1 layer deeper" at each stage.

Comment: (1) Did the result fail? Yes, if any scenario failed. (2) Did the scenario fail? Yes, if any assertion failed. (3) Did the assertion fail? Yes, if it has an error message. -- You can check for failure at any level in the hierarchy; the question just gets delegated down each layer.

Comment: To make this really complete, you *could* also define something like: `Class Newman::Assertion; def failed?; !exception_message.nil?; end; end`